# Is there any alternative way to say something you 'used to [infinitive]'?

Tags: past-tense, subjunctives

I'm talking about the use of 'used to' to mean something you did (regularly?) in your past. English has alternative ways to say something in most of the cases but here, I'm finding it very difficult.

I seek your help to find an alternative way to say this (without adding any ambiguity)

> ***I used to*** play golf.  
>  ***I used to*** love her. 
>  ***I used to*** live in Australia.

I'm keeping these sentences short with *no further detail* because I want an alternate sentence for **such construction only.** You may understand that I need an alternative for ***'I used to ...infinitive'.***

Comment: I habituated to play golf.

Comment: Interesting @LucianSava But don't you think it's used more when we are talking about getting *accustomed* and not something that we did in past? Said that, *I **am** habituated to play golf*?

Comment: @MaulikV you are correct, _habituated_ is not suitable.

Comment: _I was in the habit of playing golf_. This is equivalent to _used to_. It also doesnt say anything as excessive as _I'm habituated to playing golf_.

Comment: @ManishGiri this is good option. +1 :)

Comment: It does, however, give a different sense to 'used to'. Saying you were in the habit of playing golf almost makes it sound involuntary.

Comment: You pick up a habit voluntarily.

Comment: Maybe, but a habit is often something you can't _stop_ voluntarily, or at least easily. I'm not saying you're incorrect, I'm just saying 'I was in the habit' is not exactly synonymous with 'I used to'.

Comment: @user8543 True, for the *playing* or things the like, it may work. But if you go for the same construction in other context, it falls short. *I was in the habit of loving her.*

Comment: For state things, you can use *once*. *"I loved her once."* *"I once lived in Australia."* For action things, when you have a time phrase, saying the same thing in the simple past tense is not very different from *used to*; for example, *"I played golf every Saturday"*, *"I played golf once a month."* And you can always add, *"but not anymore"*.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to talk about a **past habit** (action), you can use the *would + action*.

> When I was young, **I used to play** football/soccer once a week.
>
> When I was young, **I would play** football/soccer once a week.

This is not the case of state verbs (such as love, live, like, feel):

> When I was a young, **I used to live** in London
>
> <strike>When I was a young, **I would live** in London</strike>

Comment: Good answer, but you do need to specify the time frame. Otherwise, the meaning can shift (as in: _If we could find a nice field, I would play football/soccer once a week_).

Answer (score 3):

If you are desperate to keep the *I ... golf* construction, I would suggest *I formerly played golf*. But it's somewhat old-fashioned sounding.

Comment: +1. This is also good option but do you think it goes same with other variations for the same structure? Say, *I used to love her?*

Comment: It's certainly grammatically correct. In terms of style it probably fits better in some cases after the verb: _I loved her, formerly_.

Comment: I see. I never knew this. Thank you. Let others comment/answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *did* + infinitive and optionally add, "but now I don't."

> I did play golf, (but now I don't).
>   I did love her, (but now I don't).
>   I did live in Australia, (but now I don't).

Comment: Another good choice. +1

Answer (score 1):

> I used to play golf.

I've come up with a couple substitues:

- Playing golf was my regular pastime for a period.
- I played golf regularly for some time.

Comment: I think I must be clearer in asking what I want. Question edited. Kindly repost this answer after change, if any.

Comment: @MaulikV, is there a reason my two examples don't fit your purpose? I've noticed the changes in your question, but the question looks basically the same.

Comment: That's because an ex-girlfriend won't like - *I loved her regularly for some time* and *Loving her was my regular pastime for a period* :) ha

Comment: I understand, you want a universal substitute. (0: For verbs denoting a repetitive activity and for those that denote a continuous state.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

> I formerly played golf.
>
> I loved her, once.
>
> I lived in Australia before.

But I'm not sure there's a universal substitute that would apply to all of these sentences.